# Url doesn't change in React Router through Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am new to use React Router. I have been trying to use it and it works when I manually change the url path. But when I use the `Link` tag to navigate to new path,it does nothing. Here's my `App.js` :

```js
const newRoute = () => {
  return (
    <div id="colorlib-page">
      <div id="container-wrap">
        <Sidebar></Sidebar>
        <div id="colorlib-main">
          <Introduction></Introduction>
          <About></About>
          <Timeline></Timeline>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
      <Sidebar></Sidebar>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={newRoute} exact/>
          <Route path="/gallery" component={Gallery} />
          <Route component={Error}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I manually go to `http://localhost:3000/gallery` it works. But Link is I guess where the problem is happening. The `Sidebar` component is where the buttons are to navigate. Here's the `Sidebar` component:

```js
export default class Sidebar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <nav href="#navbar" className="js-colorlib-nav-toggle colorlib-nav-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><i /></nav>
          <aside id="colorlib-aside" className="border js-fullheight">
            <div className="text-center">
              <div className="author-img" style={{backgroundImage: 'url(images/about1.jpg)'}} />
              <h1 id="colorlib-logo"><a href="index.html">Shuvro Sarker</a></h1>
              <span className="email"><i className="icon-mail"></i> gmail</span>
            </div>
            <nav id="colorlib-main-menu" role="navigation" className="navbar">
              <div id="navbar" className="collapse">
                <ul>
                  <li className="active"><a href="#home" data-nav-section="home">Introduction</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#about" data-nav-section="about">About</a></li>


                  // Here's the Link which isn't working

                  <Link to="/gallery">Gallery</Link>

                  <li><a href="#timeline" data-nav-section="timeline">Timeline</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
              <p><small>
                Something coming soon !!
              </small></p>
            </div>
          </aside>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

What else can I do to change the url from this Link?

Comment: Does "Gallery" appear on the list? If yes what does it show on hovering over it?

Comment: It doesn't show anything when I hover over it. It's just a blue colored text @shivangirajde

Comment: I'm not sure but you use `Sidebar` component as a wrapping component. And it doesn't have any child. Maybe it causes some bug. Can you try writing as a self closing component like this ` <Sidebar />`

Comment: I just used self closing tag but nothing changed.

Comment: try wrapping this link into li tag

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-wind-k4omd Works as expected, please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: You are using `Sidebar` in two places. One in `App` and another in `newRoute`. Which one are you interacting with?

Comment: That was a mistake. Just need to use Sidebar in App. Anyway that did not solve the issue @apopkryfos

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping you SideBar in a `withRouter` from `'react-router'`;

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class Sidebar extends Component {
    ...
}

export default withRouter(SideBar);
```

Comment: Still the same. @SerShubham

Comment: @TanmoySarker do you have a repo where this code is?

Comment: Here's the full App.js: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-silence-j2ii2  and here's the complete Sidebar: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-silence-j2ii2

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add WithRouter instead of just exporting the component.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class Gallery extends Component{
}
export default WithRouter(Gallery)
```

Comment: Tried that. Still the same.

Comment: Can u create a demo for the same in any of the online playground like stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f4eha2 refer this link for demo of react router